# zero curvature boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Is it possible to solve a differential equation 
\begin{equation}
f^{''}(x) = g(x)
\end{equation}
using finite difference method when the boundary condition is zero curvature (second derivative)?

I don't think it's possible since there would be more unknowns than the number of equations, but I'd like to know whether there is a way to keep the slope (first derivative) unchanged (i.e., zero curvature) at the boundary when solving the equation.

Thanks!

Comment: Why more unknowns than the number of equations?

Comment: @timur The zero curvature boundary condition is equivalent to setting $g(x)$ to 0 at the starting and end points. In fact, there is no boundary condition at all and thus there exist more unknowns then number of equations.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary value problem on interval $(a,b)$,
$$
f''(x)=g(x),\quad f''(a)=0, \ f''(b)=0
\tag{1}$$
is not well posed. There is no solution if $g$ does not vanish at endpoints. There are infinitely many solutions when it does: one can add any linear function to $f$ without changing the derivative.

The finite difference version of (1) will have the same problems. Generally, it is advisable to fix the well-posedness issues at the level of ODE (1) before going to the difference scheme, which will introduces issues of its own.